# Iterate over object with count as value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In a Vue application, I have a data structure like this:

```
data: () => ({
    currentKey: 1,
    currentVal: 1,
    obj: {
      1: 3,
      2: 4,
      3: 2
    }
}),
methods: {
    stepForward() {
        // this method should update currentKey and currentVal 
    }
}
```

And a **template** with a simple button to iterate through the object.

```
<p>Key:{{ currentKey }} Value: {{ currentVal }}</p>
<v-btn @click="stepForward">Next</v-btn>
```

**Problem**

Clicking on the Next button, I would like to increase the values of `currentKey` and `currentVal` by iterating through the values of `obj` line by line.

**Expected Result**

With each click on the Next button the values would increase (until the last pair is reached) as follows:

```
currentKey: 1
currentVal: 1

currentKey: 1
currentVal: 2

currentKey: 1
currentVal: 3

currentKey: 2
currentVal: 1

currentKey: 2
currentVal: 2

currentKey: 2
currentVal: 3

currentKey: 2
currentVal: 4

currentKey: 3
currentVal: 1

currentKey: 3
currentVal: 2
```

How is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend changing your object structure to be a bit more intuitive.

I'm not familiar with how vue tracks that incoming data object, but here's a rough idea:

```
if (currentVal === obj[currentKey]) {
  currentVal = 1;
  currentKey += 1;
} else {
  currentVal += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (this.currentVal === this.obj[this.currentKey]) {   
     this.currentKey += 1;
     this.currentVal = 1;
 } else {
     this.currentVal += 1;
 }
```

copy this code to your stepForward method